# Reflection to external packages in Gradle library

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to create an internal Java library with Gradle. For the SQL connection, we're using the jtds-1.3.1 package which is saved as a local jar in the libs folder.
I've added the dependency of this package into the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/jtds-1.3.1.jar')
}
```

I can now import the package without any problems. However, I need to access a class in the package using reflection, as shown below:

```
public void connect() {
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
      ...
}
```

If I now use the library in another Gradle project, it does not find the class. In order for the class to be found, I also have to copy the jtds-jar to the Libs folder in the executable Gradle project and adjust the build file.